# Ruby/Rails way of pushing array of hashes to an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmaps4rails

I am building a hash into an array and then pushing each one into one big array.  This works fine (I'm using Gmaps4Rails) but I'm wondering if there's a more Ruby way to go about it?

```
def index   
  @allpoints = []
  @links = Link.find([1, 2, 3])
  @links.each do |link|
    linkpoints = []
    link.link_points.each do |pt|
      linkpoints << { :lat => pt.latitude, :lng => pt.longitude }
    end         
    @allpoints << linkpoints
  end
  @data = @allpoints.to_json    
end
```

**SOLUTION EDIT**: (I went with the one below)  Shorter than my original, yet good enough readability in my eyes:

```
def index
  all_points = []
  Link.find([1,2,3]).each do |link|
    all_points << link.link_points.map { |pt| { lat: pt.latitude, lng: pt.longitude } }
  end
  @data = all_points.to_json
end
```

Comment: If nothing else, consider using `collect`.

Comment: is link_points a has_many association with link?

Comment: Yes, a link has_many link_points

Comment: then maybe you want to use eager loading: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Eager+loading+of+associations I'm working on a solution that uses it. Btw, your question is quite interesting to solve :)

Comment: "I'm working on a solution that uses it": Juste add `Link.includes(:link_points).find([1, 2, 3])`

Comment: Yep! I was thinking @links.includes(:link_points) but I'm also thinking if a shorter solution is possible

Comment: @Jean-Paul `@links.includes(:link_points)` could not work here since `@links` is an array, not AR::Relation

Comment: oh yes! Link instead of @links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**: you don't need to create tons of `@variables`. The ones you don't use in your views (local variables to your Controller's action) should be classic local variables.

**Second**: You could refactor your action like this:

```
@data = Link.find([1,2,3]).map do |link|
  link.link_points.map{ |pt| {lat: pt.latitude, lng: pt.longitude} }
end.to_json
```

Let me know if the code above doesn't not have the expected behavior and the output.

Comment: I liked your first/second way of doing it with Link.find([1,2,3]).each then map.  The current way you have edited to creates an extra array.

Comment: Yes this version works, but I still like your first one since it just made more sense to me, I'll edit it in my original post, but you get the answer.  Personally, too many maps gets confusing.

Comment: very fun - you replaced your code by my code from another answer, and took acceptance prize..

Comment: No, I didn't @Mik_Die. I first posted the version that Yeenow123 posted in his answer (with `all_point = []`) and then I updated my answer with shorter version. I'm sorry if the asker prefered the first version of my answer ...

Answer (score 0):

It can be refactored with `map` next way:

```
@allpoints = Link.find([1, 2, 3]).map do |link|
  link.link_points.map do |pt|
    { :lat => pt.latitude, :lng => pt.longitude }
  end
end
```